# How to add new data to dataframe in R -shiny app server

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

in my Shiny app I want to save the content of the input fields as a new row in a dataframe with an action button. I created an empty dataframe outside of the server function and wanted to add the content via rbind. This also works great in R, but obviously not in Shiny. What is my misconception?
Here is a simplified example with one field

```
library(shiny)

#create an empty dataframe
df <- data.frame(name = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("name", "Enter Name"),
  actionButton("add", "Add Data to table"),
  tableOutput ("result")
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive (data.frame(name = input$name))
    #add data to df
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    df <- rbind(df,data())
  })
    output$result <- renderTable(df)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reactiveVal` to update the data. This will be unique for each session, if you want to append to dataframe globally use `<<-`

```
library(shiny)

#create an empty dataframe
df <- data.frame(name = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("name", "Enter Name"),
  actionButton("add", "Add Data to table"),
  tableOutput ("result")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df_server <- reactiveVal(df)
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$name)
    data.frame(name = input$name)
  })
  
  #add data to df

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    temp_df <- rbind(df_server(),data())
    df_server(temp_df)
  })
  output$result <- renderTable(df_server())
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks, great ! I think I have to spend more time in the concept of reactive programming....

Comment: @Pork Chop: just one question to the solution. Why did you use  req(input$name) for the data in the reactive function?

Comment: @saibot The `req()` is for checking that the input has something in it. if you're ok with appending `NULL` or empty string `""` to your dataframe you can remove that